# Android tablet very laggy and freezing for 3 minutes (slow internal storage?)

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, chrome-for-android, app2sd, internal-sd

I have Pipo M9 Pro with Android 4.2.2

OS is quite laggy and to use Chrome is almost impossible... it is so very slow and sometimes I cannot do anything for 3-5 min because of freezing.

I made some tests with AndroBench and it looks like the internal storate is very slow. 
[image: Sequential Read]

[image: PlayStore?]

[image: SQL Lite INSERT]

Could this be the main and only problem? Also for the freezes?

Should I just get a fast SD card and link everything to there? With which app? How can I then take the card out and copy something to it?

Answer (score 0):

From the specs about your tablet on       http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/PiPo_M9_Pro
They look good.

You should check how many apps that you have running at one time, too many apps running  can slow down your device. You should check how many apps you have installed, and check that your storage isn't completely full.

I also believe that you do have a slow internal storage on that device.

As far as linking everything to SD , there is a program called Link2sd in Google Play. 
In order to use this , you will have to be rooted, as well as have a kernel that supports 
mounting an external partition.

If you want to copy something to the card manually from a pc, you would need to find the microsd card slot , take out the micro sd and then plug it into a microsd to sd adapter, or a microsd to usb adapter. Then you will be able to transfer files.

Comment: I don't have that many apps running at once and the storage isn't full. I'm now getting impatient with freezes - the system is unusuable. I don't think this is only because of slow storage, now it froze while doing something non-intensive.

Do you think custom rom can fix these freezes? I found one KitKat but it says: "This custom firmware is based on new official update dated 2013/12/26." --> but yes, it's KitKat and I have Jelly Bean, so maybe it will be better.

I was asking about removing SD card with all the apps and OS but of course this isn't smart, I'll just use USB.

Comment: If you remove a SD card , that has apps linked to it , the apps will no longer be usable until you put it back in.Linked sd cards are partitioned. So you can still move apps or other data onto the fat partition. In some cases , custom roms are great.  I have used many, and currently are still using them on some of my android devices. If I missed your question, just let me know . Good luck :).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll just try... but currently I'm trying to find out what SD card speed this tablet supports... is it 30 MH/s, 45 or even 80 ? I wrote to the company and am waiting the answer.. also I asked at slatedroid.com forum for this tablet, but no answer so far.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same freezes and all vanished with this kasty firmware. I am so happy like I bought another tablet. Go for it!

Comment: really? I just tried upgrading to firmware PIPO sent me... it's new "20140319_DS1007_M9pro_4.4.2.img" .. still froze for 1 minute while just browsing. So you think kasty could solve this? I guess I'll just try then... but it would be strange. Did they actually change anything that could influence that in their firmware? So "kasty-pipo-m9_pro-442-20131226-rooted4c_mu" is the latest "kasty" firmware? Do you know? tnx

Comment: Ok I found the latest Kasty here: http://www.arctablet.com/blog/forum/pipo-max-m9/rom-pipo-m9-pro-android-4-4-2-kitkat-custom-root-firmware-20140319/  - so it's based on the same firmware I tried earlier today and was freezing.. I'll try Kasty but can I reasonably expect it to be better?

Comment: Tried it... Chrome froze immediately for 2 minutes :/ "Chrome isn't responding - Do you want to close it?". Very disappointed... I just hope something can be done about it.